# VBA Find Function cannot define a variable range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the VBA `Find()` function but am unable to make the find function only search within a specific range. Could someone kindly help me with this?

I'm getting a Run-time error '1004' application define or object define error on `y = Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(frow, k)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value 'full soln max`

I'm trying to define the range between for my find function to search within. Its from the 10th row to whatever row the text "GLOBAL GROUP PURCHASES" is in.

Below is the code:

```
Sub highlightcases()   
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
    k = 2 * i - 1
    For j = 13 To Sheets(1).Cells.Find("GLOBAL GROUP PURCHASES").Offset(-2, 0).Row
      ID = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value 'case comparison stream name      
      frow = Cells.Find("GLOBAL GROUP PURCHASES").Row      
      x = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value 'case comparison sheet activity
      y = Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(frow, 1)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value 'full soln max      
      Z = Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(frow, 1)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 5).Value ' full soln min      

      If x = y And x <> 0 And y <> Z Then 'check max        
        Sheets(1).Cells(j, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
      ElseIf x = Z And x <> 0 And y <> Z Then 'check min
        Sheets(1).Cells(j, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
      ElseIf y = Z And y <> 0 Then 'check fixed
        Sheets(1).Cells(j, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
      End If

      If Sheets(1).Cells(j, k).Value <> 0 Then      
        Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets(1).Cells(j, k), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                "'" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!" & Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(frow, 1)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 3).Address, TextToDisplay:=Sheets(1).Cells(j, k).Text
      Else      
        Sheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets(1).Cells(j, k), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                "'" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!" & Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(Cells.Find("GLOBAL GROUP PURCHASES").Row, 1)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 3).Address, TextToDisplay:="0"
      End If

    Next j
  Next i

  With Sheets(1).Cells    
   .Font.Color = vbBlack
   .Font.Size = 8
   .Font = Arial    
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you already do that when setting `y` and `Z`?

Comment: Yes that's the problem. It's giving me an error

Comment: Then you need to describe that error (the exact error message) and the line where it occurs.

Comment: Sorry i'll edit the question again. I'm getting a Run-time error '1004'
application define or object define error on 
   y = Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(frow, k)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value 'full soln max

Comment: are you sure that the `ID` exists in the range you are searching for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 y = Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(frow, 1)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value
```

Here's your problem: `Cells(10, 1)` refers to the cell A10, obviously. But on which sheet? Because you didn't specify it, it takes the currently active sheet so it is essentially the same as `ActiveSheet.Cells(10,1)`.

You did correctly specify the sheet for the `.Range` but later you don't specify it for the `Cells` so if, let's say, `Sheet(1)` is the active sheet and i=2, your line is the same as

```
y = Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(10, 1), Sheets(1).Cells(frow, 1)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value
```

and you can't specify a range on one sheet with cells from another sheet.The solution is, of course, to always specify the sheets. `With` blocks can make that easier

```
With Sheets(i)
    y = .Range(.Cells(10, 1), .Cells(frow, 1)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value 
End With
```

whenever you use `.Something` in a with block, it uses `.Something` on the with block variable. Of course you would put more than one line inside, possibly everything within the inner for loop.

Comment: Thanks! but i'm getting a Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set"  after using yours or RGA's code.
Nvm my mistake. its a .find error which i've resolved. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcusChua yep, always assign a range first and then check if it's `Nothing` before getting its row or column (or property)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `Find` on the cells object, call it on the specific range you want to search.  So if you wanted to search the first column, call `Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find("GLOBAL GROUP PURCHASES").Offset(-2, 0).Row` or even `Sheets(1).Columns(1).Find("GLOBAL GROUP PURCHASES").Offset(-2, 0).Row`.   For a named range, defined by a variable, use `Sheets(1).Range(YourRangeVariableName).Find("GLOBAL GROUP PURCHASES").Offset(-2, 0).Row`

This can be done for any range of any shape or size

In answer to the error thrown, when using a sheet and Range call, you need to specify the sheet again for the cells, so instead of `y = Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(frow, k)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value`, you need to call `y = Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Cells(10, 1), Sheets(i).Cells(frow, k)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value`.   This occurs because any Cell or Range called without a specified sheet will call from the active sheet, so if `Sheets(i)` is not the active sheet, you will get cells that cannot be a in the `Sheets(i).Range()`

Comment: Thanks! But I can't search the entire column because there are repesting values

Comment: @MarcusChua then adjust the specified Range to the range that you need

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do. But where 'global group purchases' is changes.

Comment: @MarcusChua I can't read minds, so you'd have to tell me what the range is you need to search if you wanted me to write code for you.  However, I'm not going to write it because you will learn much more about VBA by trying first for yourself.  Use the answer I've given as a pointer in the right direction, and try to figure out how to use the correct range.  If you cannot, then open a new question and ask for help with that separate problem

Comment: Sorry maybe i didnt explain myself clearly. I'm getting a Run-time error '1004' application define or object define error on y = Sheets(i).Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(frow, k)).Find(ID).Offset(0, 6).Value. 

I'm trying to define the range between for my find function to search within. Its from the 10th row to whatever row the text "GLOBAL GROUP PURCHASES" is in.

Comment: @MarcusChua I editted my answer to include that fix.  In the future, always specify your error when you ask the question first (to avoid this type of confusion)

Comment: Nvm my mistake. its a .find error which i've resolved. Thank you so much!